# SqlTransaction after catch transaction connection is null

Tags: c#, transactions, connection, try-catch, sqltransaction

I have a loop where I call stored procedure with different parameter value.
Next call `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`
I use transaction to save all or rollback, and checkBox2 - save always.
I found one problem and I can't find solution.
After first problem when catch block is fired transaction object loses its connection.
`t.connection` is null!
Everything is good but transaction object is without connection *at start it has!*

```
    try 
        {

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            strLine.Remove(0, strLine.Length);
            //c = sr.ReadLine();

             while (c != "-")
              {
               c = sr.ReadLine();
               strLine.Append(c );
               if (sr.EndOfStream) break;
              }

             //strLine.Append("Nowa pozycja");
             try
             {
                 cmd.Parameters["@s"].Value = strLine.ToString();
                 cmd.Parameters["@Return_value"].Value = null;
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
             catch
             {
                 if (cmd.Parameters["@Return_value"].Value == null)
                 {
                     cmd.Parameters["@Return_value"].Value = -100;
                 }

                 if (((int)cmd.Parameters["@Return_value"].Value == 100) || (checkBox2.Checked))
                 {
                     if ((int)cmd.Parameters["@Return_value"].Value != 100)
                     {
                         MessageBox.Show("Są błedy!   " + cmd.Parameters["@s"].Value);
                     };
                 }
             }

         if (!checkBox2.Checked)
         {
             if ((Int32)cmd.Parameters["@Return_value"].Value != 100)
             {
                 break;
             }
         }

        c = "";
        }
        textBox1.Text = strLine.ToString();


        }
     catch
        {
          // t.Rollback();
         //  t = null;
           textBox1.Text = strLine.ToString();
           textBox1.Visible = true;
           MessageBox.Show("Wystąpiły problemy w czasie importu  " + cmd.Parameters["@s"].Value);
           //return;
        }

        finally
        {
            if (cmd.Parameters["@Return_value"].Value == null)
            {
                cmd.Parameters["@Return_value"].Value = -100;
            }

            if (((int)cmd.Parameters["@Return_value"].Value==100)||(checkBox2.Checked)) 
            {
                t.Commit();  
                if ((int)cmd.Parameters["@Return_value"].Value!=100)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Transakcja zapisana ale w pliku były błedy!   " + cmd.Parameters["@s"].Value);
                };
            }
        else
        { 
           if (t!=null) {t.Rollback();}
           MessageBox.Show("Transakcja odrzucona!");
        }


        conn2.Close();
        aFile.Close();
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You're missing a fair amount of code in that block.  I'd say your first step is going to be to simplify it a bit AND post the whole block.  Also, I would consider *not* putting braces on their own line; it's harder to scan a large block of code with so much whitespace in it. (but that's my opinion)

Comment: How do you set up your connection and transaction?

Comment: I set up they:            if (conn2.State != ConnectionState.Open) conn2.Open();
            SqlTransaction t= conn2.BeginTransaction();

Comment: Hard to know where to start with this, did you have a goal of breaking near every rule of writing decent code as a design requirement? The first problem is you don't do try catch anything. The second is if you do, you don't assume which exception could have been thrown. Break the code up so you can see what's going on, and only catch exceptions you can deal with.

Comment: Problem is simply. Object Transaction t losts its Connection value when catch happened.

Comment: i agree the catch should probably target a specific exception, but his code formatting besides that is CORRECT.  Recommended guidelines in c# put brackets like he has them.

Answer (score 3):

Ran into a similar issue. In my case it was happening for a specific SqlException. Most exceptions would be caught and handled just fine, but whenever I got a conversion error (such as trying to convert a string to a number) it would automatically end the transaction.

To fix this, I had to implement data checking (good idea anyway) prior to building/submitting the command object. Hope this helps others seeing this weird error.

Answer (score 1):

I also met this odd problem (converting nvarchar to integer exception).

In my solution, I rebuild the transacton if found the underlying connection is null. But it's a dirty work.

[image]