# C# SqlTransaction.Commit throw exception because Connection is null

Tags: c#, database-connection, sqltransaction

I have a problem using SqlTransaction. Here's the code

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
// assume that at this point I add try/catch and the connection is successfully opened.
conn.Open();
SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead);

//.........
// Here I do my action with database, change it, commit, call ExecuteNonQuery, //ExecuteScalar,etc...

// And after that long processing with this transaction, I don't know why trans.Connection //is null. and therefore when I call trans.commit(), an exception was raised?


trans.commit();
```

Does anybody have any clues?

I assume this might be because of memory of database server was ate up because of too much connections. But I'm not sure.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is it real code? You have SqlConnection conn but then use con

Answer (score 1):

Seems like typo

```
con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)
```

should be

```
conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.RepeatableRead)
```

Answer (score 1):

make use of using

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("ServerVersion: {0}", connection.ServerVersion);
        Console.WriteLine("State: {0}", connection.State);
    }
```

Comment: SqlConnection was successfully opened, and this bug occurs inconsitently, meaning normally my application runs well but sometimes, it throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

use a `using` statement:

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
//your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

c# - SqlTransaction after catch transaction connection is null - Stack Overflow
[SqlTransaction after catch transaction connection is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839631/sqltransaction-after-catch-transaction-connection-is-null)

Edyn said that:
Ran into a similar issue. In my case it was happening for a specific SqlException. Most exceptions would be caught and handled just fine, but whenever I got a conversion error (such as trying to convert a string to a number) it would automatically end the transaction.

In my solution, I rebuild the transacton if found the underlying connection is null. But it's a dirty work.